# Fill in table based a column of categories in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Type     Value
Movie    5
Food     3
Gas      10
Food     2
....     ....
```

And There's a second table I want to fill in with "Value" based on their type in the first table, so that  the corresponding rows look like this:

```
Rent  Food  Movie  Gas  Clothing   ... ( appear in specific order bc they are subcategories)
            5
      3
                   10
      2
```

The title row is already there, so I was thinking there might be some kind of lookup method to do this? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

your second table apperas to hold one value per row but it doesn't have a label.  it does correlate to the original row number, is this by design or coincidence?

if this is by design then you can use those 2 columns, hide them if you like, get a unique list of categories by copying you r abels to a new colum, removing duplicates in the data tab, then paste special transpose in c1 to create colum headers.

so column a and b remain unchanged
row 1 contains header starting at column c
your data starts at c2
this is the formula

`=Iferror(vlookup(C$1,$A2:$B2,2,false),"")`

drag it down and to the right
you can copy paste special values when done to remove the formulas

for something with only a hundred or thousand cells this will be one of the easier options but i would not do this on large tables, for those i would use power query or VBA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 1st table is in Sheet1 and 2nd table is in sheet2..  you may try to fill in Sheet2!A2

```
=IF(Sheet1!$A2=A$1,Sheet1!$B2,"")
```

and drag it all the way.. Hope you get how it works.. and what you need.